# Importing Scanned PDF Extracted text to CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv, dataframe, python-tesseract

I have extracted text from scanned PDF using Tesseract. I've got output string as something like this..

```
Haemoglobin 13.5 14-16 g/dl
Random Blood Sugar 186 60 - 160 mg/dl
Random Urine Sugar Nil
¢ Blood Urea 43 14-40 mg/dl
4 — Serum Creatinine 2.13 0.4-1.5 mg/dl
Serum Uric Acid 4.9 3.4-7.0 mg/dl
Serum Sodium 142 135 - 150 meq/L
/ Serum Potassium 2.6 3.5-5.0 meq/L
Total Cholesterol] 146 110 - 160 mg/dl
Triglycerides 162 60 - 180 mg/d]
```

Now i have to feed this to a dataframe or a csv with all the text in one column and values in other i.e..

```
**Haemoglobin**            13.5   14-16     g/dl
**Random Blood Sugar**     186    60 - 160  mg/dl
```

so far, the best i could get through this is something like this...

```
  text = text.split('\n')
  text = [x.split(' ') for x in text]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns['Header','Detail','a','e,','b','c','d','f'])
df

    Header    Detail   a      e     b      c      d  f
0 Haemoglobin 13.5    14-16   g/dl  None   None  None  None
1 Random      Blood   Sugar   186   60      -     160  mg/dl
2 Random      Urine   Sugar   Nil   None   None  None  None
```

Please help!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Is it always a numerical value after the header? or can it also be a range such as "14-16" as well?

Comment: i split each line of text by space and created a data frame.             text = [re.split(' ') for x in text]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['Header','Detail','a','e,','b', 'c','d','f'])
df

Answer (score 1):

I should point that this needs a lot of work and honestly you haven't tried anything yet. But to give you a head start here's a code that cleans up some of the obvious problems in your input:

```
import re
def isnum(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def clean_line(lnin):
    # clean the leading garbage
    ln=re.sub('^[^A-Za-z]+','',lnin).split()
    for i in range(len(ln)):
        if isnum(ln[i]):
            ind=i
            break
    Header=' '.join(ln[:ind])
    ln=[Header]+ln[ind:]
    if '-' in ln:
        ind=ln.index('-')
        ln[ind-1]=ln[ind-1]+'-'+ln[ind+1]
        del ln[ind:ind+2]
    return ln
```

Use the `clean_line` function to clean each of your lines. Then you can feed it to a dataframe.

Comment: ln=Header+ln[ind:] at this line getting an error 'must be str, not list'.

Comment: sorry, change it to `ln=[Header]+ln[ind:]`

Comment: @AishwaryaVenkat It's not easy to use regex when you have many different patterns. for example in the line `Random Urine Sugar Nil` what is the rule of what goes to header and what goes to the rest? I've assumed there is always a float, and if you remove that line from your data the code works fine. But for general solution you need an exception handler.

Comment: That worked like charm! Thanku so much :D Now i could sleep peacefully

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept it as an answer then.

Answer (score -1):

Work backwards from the end, since the rest of the record seems to be fixed format, i.e., working backwards,

string representing units (this has no spaces) :
number : 
dash : 
number : 
number :
the text you want

```
Haemoglobin 13.5 14-16 g/dl
Field 5 (all characters backwards from end until space reached) = g/gl
Field 4 (jump over space, all characters backwards until space or dash reached) = 16
Field 3 (jump over space if present, pick up dash) = -
Field 2 (jump over space if present, all characters backwards until space reached) = 14
Field 1 (jump over space, all characters backwards until space reached) = 13.5
Field 0 (jump over space and take the rest) = Haemoglobin

Total Cholesterol] 146 110 - 160 mg/dl
Field 5 (all characters backwards from end until space reached) = mg/dl
Field 4 (jump over space, all characters backwards until space or dash reached) = 160
Field 3 (jump over space if present, pick up dash) = -
Field 2 (jump over space if present, all characters backwards until space reached) = 110
Field 1 (jump over space, all characters backwards until space reached) = 146
Field 0 (jump over space and take the rest) = Total Cholesterol]
```

Comment: This is not a solution to her problem, more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Rephrased a little, but I don't see why this is not an answer - I would do what I have suggested, if I needed to load this data. Or are you saying I need to provide full code to implement this suggestion? (If so, as I am not a Python developer, I will have to delete my answer.)

Comment: A sample snippet to deal with would be helpful :D

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Using regular expressions the below sample code will parse the text to a CSV string with the tokens: description, result, normal_value, unit.

Note the list test_results is usually read from a file using:

with open('name_test_file') as test_file:
    test_results = test_file.read().splitlines()

```
import re
tests = 'Haemoglobin 13.5 14-16 g/dl\nRandom Blood Sugar 186 60 - 160 mg/dl\n'\
    'Random Urine Sugar Nil\n¢ Blood Urea 43 14-40 mg/dl\n'\
    '4 — Serum Creatinine 2.13 0.4-1.5 mg/dl\n'\
    'Serum Uric Acid 4.9 3.4-7.0 mg/dl\nSerum Sodium 142 135 - 150 meq/L\n'\
    '/ Serum Potassium 2.6 3.5-5.0 meq/L\n'\
    'Total Cholesterol] 146 110 - 160 mg/dl\n'\
    'Triglycerides 162 60 - 180 mg/d]\n'

test_results = tests.splitlines()

for test_result in test_results:
    print('input :', test_result)

    m = re.search(r'.*?(?=[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(?P<description>.*?)(?=[ ][0-9])'
              r'[ ](?P<result>[0-9.]*?)(?=[ ][0-9])'
              r'[ ](?P<normal_value>[ 0-9.\-]*?)(?=[ ][a-zA-Z])'
              r'[ ](?P<unit>.[ a-zA-Z/]*)',
              test_result)

    if m is not None:
        normal_value = m.group('normal_value')
        unit = m.group('unit')

    else:
        m = re.search(r'.*?(?=[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(?P<description>.*?)(?=[ ]Nil)'
                  r'[ ](?P<result>Nil).*',
                  test_result)
        normal_value = ''
        unit = ''

    if m is not None:
        description = m.group('description')
        result = m.group('result')

    else:
        description = test_result
        result = ''

    write_string = description + ',' + result + ',' + normal_value + ',' + unit
    print(write_string)
```

Comment: I spent some time to produce the above code to help you out, so appreciate if you can remove your down vote! Thanks...

Comment: I don't think the OP /can/ downvote yet, must have been someone else.